# How to map the relationship between entities?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to figure out how to correctly map the following relationship between entities

user {id, name}

movie { id, movieName, description}

rating { id, rating }

user can perform the operation of rating a movie and retrieve all movies rated.
Can someone please help regarding defining relationship between rating and other entities?

```
@Entity
public class Rating {

    @Id
    private long id;

    private String rating;

    ??? What goes here ????????
    private User user;

    ??? What goes here ????????
    private Movie movie;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Foreign keys are missing in the table `rating`. The ids of the tables have been renamed to make the relationship more "visible".

```
user {user_id, name}

movie { movie_id, movieName, description}

rating { rating_id, rating, user_id, movie_id }
```

A rating is given to a movie by a user, thus entity will look as such;

```
@Entity
public class Rating {

    @Id
    private long id;

    private String rating;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id", referencedColumnName = "movie_id")
    private Movie movie;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a many to many relationship between User and Movie (a user can rate many movies and a movie can be rated by many users). Here is an example mapping below:

***User:***

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    // other fields

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Rating> ratings = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addRating(Rating rating) {
        ratings.add(rating);
        rating.setUser(this);
    }

    public void removeRating(Rating rating) {
        ratings.remove(rating);
        rating.setUser(null);
    }

    // getter, setter, contsructors
}
```

***Rating:***

```
@Entity
public class Rating {

    @EmbeddedId
    private RatingId ratingId = new RatingId();

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer rating;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("userId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("movieId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Movie movie;

    // getter, setter, contsructors
}
```

***RatingId:***

```
@Embeddable
public class RatingId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private Long userId;

    @Column(name = "movie_id", nullable = false)
    private Long movieId;
}
```

***Movie:***

```
@Entity
public class Movie {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "movie", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Rating> ratings = new HashSet<>();

    public void addRating(Rating rating) {
        ratings.add(rating);
        rating.setMovie(this);
    }

    public void removeRating(Rating rating) {
        ratings.remove(rating);
        rating.setMovie(null);
    }

    // getters, setters, constructors
}
```