# Spring JPA Many-to-one relationship, from an existing database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have an already existing database and I need to rebuild it in my Spring Boot project. In the database there are relationships already formed across tables, and I fail to recreate them. Up to this point I have used tables without foreign keys and everything went well, but now that I try to implement the Many-To-One relationship the project doesn't start. I attach the structure of the table, the relationships are unidirectional and my Event class code that tries to create a relationship with the Tipologia Table.[Table Evento](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2miCI.png)[Foreign key, Table Evento](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aVoN.png)[Code for Class Evento](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f072H.png). [No foreign key here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6cHS.png).

```
@Entity
@Table(name= "evento")
public class Evento {
    @Id
    @Column(name= "idevento")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    (other code...)

    @ManyToOne( cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name = "idtipologia")// nome del campo che punta alla tabella Tipologia.
    private Tipologia tipologia;

    public Tipologia getTipologia(Tipologia tipologia){
        return tipologia;
    }

    public void setTipologia(Tipologia tipologia){
        this.tipologia = tipologia;
    }
}

Table Tipologia: 

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "tipologia")
    public class Tipologia {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "idtipologia")
    private int idtipologia;

    @Column(name = "tipologia")
    private String tipologia;


    public Tipologia(){ }

    public Tipologia(int idtipologia, String tipologia){
        this.idtipologia = idtipologia;
        this.tipologia = tipologia;
    }

    public String getTipologia(){return tipologia;}
    public void setTipologia(String tipologia){this.tipologia = tipologia;}

    public int getIdtipologia(){return idtipologia;}

    public void setIdtipologia(int idtipologia){this.idtipologia = idtipologia;}

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tipologia")
    private List<Evento> Eventi;


}
```

I did several tests, read the Hibernate documentation. Nothing I've done seems to work. From what appears from the structure of the "Evento" Table, I should have an integer type "idtipologia" field which is connected to the "idtipologia" primary key of the "Tipologia" Table, unfortunately I cannot understand how to arrive at this result. This is only for the "idtipologia" field. here is the error:
< No property 'idtipologia' found for type 'Evento'; Did you mean 'tipologia'. >.I have some code in the repository to search for events by idtipologia.

Comment: Could you check the example given in my answer on [How to map the relationship between entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75529876/how-to-map-the-relationship-between-entities/75541976#75541976)?